# mysql count performance

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

```
select count(*) from mytable;
select count(table_id) from mytable; //table_id is the primary_key
```

both query were running slow on a table with 10 million rows.
I am wondering why since wouldn't it easy for mysql to keep a counter that gets updated on all insert,update and delete?
and is there a way to improve this query?   I used explain but didn't help much.

Comment: What storage engine is mytable?

Comment: @cherouvim my money says `InnoDB`, since `MyISAM` does keep a row counter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As cherouvim pointed out in the comments, it depends on the storage engine.

`MyISAM` does keep a count of the table rows, and can keep it accurate since the only locks MyISAM supports is a table lock.

`InnoDB` however supports transactions, and needs to do a table scan to count the rows.

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/12/01/count-for-innodb-tables/

Comment: Hopefully InnoDB would do a full index scan rather than a full table scan

Comment: @Mark Whats the difference? (since there is no WHERE, and InnoDB stores the data in the primary key index)

Comment: I was thinking more of when there is a WHERE clause, which is probably more common when using COUNT; but an index scan should generally be faster than a table scan

Answer (score 8):

take a look at the following blog posts:

1) [COUNT(***) vs COUNT(col)](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/)
2) [Easy MySQL Performance Tips](http://maisonbisson.com/blog/post/11796/easy-mysql-performance-tips/)
3) [Fast count(*) for InnoDB](http://mysqlha.blogspot.com/2009/08/fast-count-for-innodb.html)

btw, which engine do you use?

**EDITED:** About technique to speed up count when you need just to know if there are some amount of rows. Sorry, just was wrong with my query. So, when you need just to know, if there is e.g. 300 rows by specific condition you can try subquery:

```
select count(*) FROM
( select 1 FROM _table_ WHERE _conditions_ LIMIT 300 ) AS result
```

at first you minify result set, and then count the result; it will still scan result set, but you can limit it (once more, it works when the question to DB is "is here more or less than 300 rows), and if DB contains more than 300 rows which satisfy condition that query is faster

Testing results (my table has 6.7mln rows):

1) `SELECT count(*) FROM _table_ WHERE START_DATE > '2011-02-01'`
returns **4.2mln for 65.4 seconds**

2) `SELECT count(*) FROM ( select 1 FROM _table_ WHERE START_DATE > '2011-02-01' LIMIT 100 ) AS result`
returns **100 for 0.03 seconds**

Below is result of the explain query to see what is going on there:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) FROM ( select 1 FROM _table_ WHERE START_DATE > '2011-02-01' LIMIT 100 ) AS result
```

[image]

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: I checked it, as result was better performance, so it tell that yes... But wait.. I don't remember if I used MySQL or PostgreSQL, it matters...

Comment: As expected, the `LIMIT` solution you provided does not work. `LIMIT` goes on the rows returned

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: edited, just gave wrong query. now it works as expected ;)

Comment: @maxym replace `_row_` in the inner query, with a constant like `SELECT 1`. can you please post the `EXPLAIN` output? does it copy the inner query to a temp table first?

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: sure, give me a minute

Comment: @maxym Thx +1. and btw `COUNT` with a `WHERE` will not be quicker if the engine was MyISAM

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: Thank you for checking and pointing to my mistake!